# I'm not getting any test coverage below

Tags: unit-test

```
public class EmailDistributerTemplate
{
    public Id accountId {get;set;}

    public list<account> getLocation()
    {
        list<account> locationadd;
        locationadd=[select id,Phone,(select Street_1__c,City__c,State_Province__c,ZipCode__c,County__c FROM Addressbook__r WHERE Primary_Address__c = TRUE) from account where id =:accountId ];
                                                       
                                                                                                             
        return locationadd;
    }
}
```

```
@isTest
public class EmailDistributerTemplateTest {
    
    @istest static void test_emailDistributer()
        
    {
        Account accRec = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Territory_Code__c ='North',COG_Clinic_Type__c ='zoo');
        insert accRec;
        
        id accountId = acc.id;
        
        Addressbook__r  address = new LocationAddress__c(Street_1__c = 'Uk',State_Province__c = 'South',ZipCode__c='400101',County__c='California',Account__c = acc.Id;);
        insert address
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't call the method EmailDistributerTemplate.getLocation

Thats why you don't get coverage for it.

Comment: Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: List<Account> EmailDistributerTemplate.getLocation()

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not `static`, so you need to create an instance of your class in the unit test.

```
EmailDistributerTemplate controller = new EmailDistributerTemplate();
controller.accountId = acc.Id;
Account[] results = EmailDistributerTemplate.getLocation();
```

This should be done after creating the test data (the code you've already written).